# Problems Retrieving Data from Firebase in Swift 3

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase, store it in an array which will then be used as a reference for another firebase query. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work properly. The print function at the bottom is always empty. I have tried to call each successive function after the for loops, but I'm probably doing it wrong.

I have 2 branches in firebase that looks a bit like this:

```
-id
 |
 Group1
   |
   ID01: Created on 01.01.16


-idDetails
 |
 ID01
  //name: name01
  //description: description01
```

This is my code:

```
var array = [String]()
var id = [String]()
var items = [Item]() //Item Class Array

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getIdFromFirebase()


}

//first task
func getIdFromFirebase(){
    for index in array //index is being used as part of path query
    {
     FireDbase_Main.child("Group1").child("id").child(index).observe(FIRDataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.id = (snapshot.key)
            id.append(id)
        })
    getDataForItems()
    }
 }

//second task
func getDataForItems() {
    let newItem = Item()
    for index in id //i is being used as part of path query
    {
    FireDbase_Main.child("idDetails").child(index).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    newItem.itemID = snapshot.key
    newItem.name = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["name"] as! String
    newItem.desc = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["description"] as! String
    self.items.append(newItem)
  }
printItemsArray(
}
   //3rd Task: For now I have put a print here just as a placeholder task.
 func printItemsArray(){
   print(items.map {$0.itemID})
   print(items.map {$0.name})
   print(items.map {$0.desc})
}
```

Comment: firebase result are async and you are calling `printItemsArray` before even getting the result print inside the result closure

Comment: Thank you for helping me realize the problem :) Do you know how I can force it to wait till it has finished getting the data before printing?

Comment: call the print function from closure

Comment: And you are creating loop of firebase call thats not good fetch all `id` from `Group` once and filter it instead of creating loop of calls

Comment: Ok thanks for the information, I'll try to rearrange my data so that I don't need loops to retrieve it.